# Django 2.1 unable to detect my new models during makemigrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I've been searching on how to fix this. These are the things that i tried before posting this question. Unfortunately none of them worked.

- Added the app name (myapp) in setting's INSTALLED_APPS list, it Didn't work.
- Tried adding just the app name, but it didn't work as well. So now I'm using the full dotted path (myapp.settings.MyappConfig) just to be safe.
- Deleted `__pycache__/*.pyc`

When I run `$ python manage.py showmigrations`, i can see that "myapp" is recognized but there's no migration.

I've placed all my models in a folder to organize it. See my folder structure below. What am I missing here? This is so frustrating, please help me. Thanks in advance!

```
mysite
|__myapp
|   |__ models
|   |   |__ __init__.py
|   |   |__ project.py 
|   |
|   |___ apps.py
|   |___ admin.py #<-- register your models here
|
|__mysite
   |__ settings.py
```

## Update: FIXED!

---

I was able to generate the migrations scripts by registering the model in admin.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/

With this, you can now organize the models into folders. No need to define the modules in `__init__.py`.

Hopefully someone find this useful. Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a `migrations` folder inside the app and there is a `__init__.py` inside it. Same goes to models folder, you should make sure there is `__init__.py` file there. Else python will not recognize it a module.
Also inside the init file(for model), you need to import the Model classes like this:

```
from .project import ProjectModel
```

Or you can run `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` create the migration folder.

Comment: oh yeah i forgot to include this. I also did this but still no luck.

Comment: inside `__init__.py` (for model) can you do it like: `from .project import ProjectModel`? @Wreeecks

Comment: Then run makemigrations

Comment: Do i need to this for all the models in the folder?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. As django recognizes on `models.py`, bascially what you are doing is that making the folder `models` as a module, so inside `__init__.py`, it should have all the model class references